# How to jackson serialize naming by value?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Some api need json like this：

```json
{
  "token_123213p123": ""
}
```

the `token_123213p123` is dynamic, so I create a class:

```java
@Data
public class Entity {
  // I will set 'token_123213p123' in this
  @JsonIgnore
  private String token;
}
```

so how to when serialize to add `"token_123213p123": ""` from `token`

Comment: You could use a `Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Map<>**:

```
static class Data {
    public Map<String, String> map;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Data data = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"map\": {\"foo\": \"bar\", \"bar\": \"foo\"}}", Data.class);
    data.map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", k, v));
}
```

with output

```
foo: bar
bar: foo
```